# Что делает asyncio.loop.call_exception_handler()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio

Что делает asyncio.loop.call_exception_handler() ?
В [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.call_exception_handler) много параметров, но не понятно зачем эта конструкция нужна.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59520811/5909792